# Cloud flow activity monitor empty - Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

I am attempting to monitor my Power Automate cloud flows, using the build-in Monitor.
So when I go to **make.powerautomate.com** and sign in, go to **Monitor** in the left pane and the click **Cloud flow activity**, all I see is this screen below.
[image]
I then used **Create from blank** to create a new and very simple flow. And the ran it.
Now I would expect something to show up under **All Activity**. But the image remains unchanged.

Does anyone know what i am missing?
(yes I have refreshed the page)

I also have many flow already existing on this environment in solutions. And as you can see they do not show up here either.

Comment: What kind of triggers did you use in your existing flows? Manually trigger a flow trigger, scheduled trigger or a product specific trigger (when an email arrives, when a file is created, etc.)? Afaik manually run flow instances don't show up in this overview.

Comment: More or less all kinds. Its a production environment that has been very active for a long time

Comment: In that case it might be good to contact Power Automate support about this and see if they can help you with this? https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/support/